Reducer function in redux gets called multiple times
Please someone make me understand the underlying behavior of redux. Here is my reducer function with one case:
  case INCREASE_QTY:
      return state.map((product) => {
        if (product.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...product,
            data: {
              ...product.data,
              qty: product.data.qty + action.payload.qty,
            },
          };
        }
        console.log('hello')
        return product;
      });

In above case, I was mistakenly returning state instead of product outside the if block. This was causing unexpected behavior.
action creator:
export const increaseQty = (id, qty) => {
  return {
    type: INCREASE_QTY,
    payload: {
      id,
      qty,
    },
  };
};

and dispatching action:
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { increaseQty } from '../redux/productSlice/actions';
import { deleteFromCart } from '../redux/cartSlice/actions';

const CartCard = ({ product }) => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    const correspondingProduct = cart.productInfo.find(
      (product) => product.id === id
    );

    dispatch(deleteFromCart(correspondingProduct.id));
    dispatch(increaseQty(correspondingProduct.id, correspondingProduct.qty));
  };

  return (
    <div className="cartCard">
      <div className="flex items-center col-span-6 space-x-6">
        <img className="cartImage" src={product.data.image} alt="product" />

        <div className="space-y-2">
          <h4 className="cartName">{product.data.name}</h4>
          <p className="cartCategory">{product.data.category}</p>
          <p>
            BDT <span className="cartPrice">{product.data.price}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="flex items-center justify-center col-span-2 mt-4 md:justify-end md:mt-0">
        <button
          className="removeFromCart"
          onClick={() => deleteHandler(product.id)}
        >
          <i className="text-lg text-red-400 fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartCard;

My question is, if I have multiple products in cart and wanna delete an item, the unexpected behavior was it was deleting all items. However I found that I was doing wrong in the reducer function. But I want to understand, if the ID matches, hello should not pe printed on the console. And thus the unexpected behavior would not happen. But in this case, console.log() is being called though the if block is executed. Why?
Thanks in advance.

Please follow the official Redux tutorial to learn modern Redux with Redux Toolkit. The legacy Redux style you are writing here is superseeded for half a decade, and it's much more difficult to learn and write. There will not be anymore switch..case reducers, no mapping over state arrays etc. - you can just write mutating code in createSlice reducers, which will make most of your question here obsolete.

You can also mix modern style into old Redux code, so even in a legacy Redux app you can just switch over to createSlice reducers. There is really no more reason to use the legacy style in new code.

I know Redux Toolkit and RTK query as well. However, I just want to know the underlying behavior in here. How the code flow is working.

In that case, have you seen the fundamentals tutorial?

Array.prototype.map() runs for all the elements of the array. The return statement is not used to break out of the loop, as you are expecting. It is used to transform an element of an array and return a new element.
The reducer for the INCREASE_QTY will do this:
It will run the callback for all elements of state and transform the one where id matches, and return rest all products as it is.

Thanks a lot. Got the point. However, I was not expecting the return statement break the map() loop. I thought this (multiple call) is happening due to reduxs' internal behavior. I totally missed the map function's loop here.
